# Multiple Input Validation with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a webform in which a user has to fill in details. I am using Javascript and html in order to do multiple input validation with regular expressions. I have part of the javascript + html code below. The variables a-g are regexes of each input field required.

I created an empty Array called Err_arr to  stored the errors that has met the conditions (e.g. if the user does not input anything / if the user does not fulfil the required format of input) The error message will be pushed into the array. The last if statement will be used to check whether the array is not empty, hence it will print out all the error messages on multiple lines depending on what the conditions are.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var cname = document.getElementById("cname").value;
  var odate = document.getElementById("odate").value;
  var cno = document.getElementById("cno").value;
  var ccn = document.getElementById("ccn").value;
  var expm = document.getElementById("expm").value;
  var expy = document.getElementById("expy").value;
  var cvv = document.getElementById("cvv").value;

  var Err_Arr = [];
  var a = /^(\w\w+)\s(\w+)$/;
  var b = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;
  var c = /[0-9]{8}/;
  var d = /[0-9]{16}/;
  var e = /0[0-1]1[0-9]){2}/;
  var f = /[0-9]{4}/;
  var g = /[0-9]{3}/;

  if (cname == null || cname == "") {
    Err_Arr.push("Please Enter Info - Customer Name");
  }
  if (odate == null || odate == "") {
    Err_Arr.push("Please Enter Info - Order Date");
  }
  if (cno == null || cno == "") {
    Err_Arr.push("Please Enter Info - Contact No");
  }
  if (ccn == null || ccn == "") {
    Err_Arr.push("Please Enter Info - Credit Card Number");
  }
  if (expm == null || expm == "") {
    Err_Arr.push("Please Enter Info - Expiry Month");
  }
  if (expy == null || expy == "") {
    Err_Arr.push("Please Enter Info - Expiry Year");
  }
  if (cvv == null || cvv == "") {
    Err_Arr.push("Please Enter Info - CVV No");
  }
  if (cname.test(a) == false) {
    Err_Arr.push("Enter correct input");
  }

  if (odate.test(b) == false) {
    Err_Arr.push("Enter correct input");
  }

  if (cno.test(c) == false) {
    Err_Arr.push("Enter correct input");
  }

  if (ccn.test(d) == false) {
    Err_Arr.push("Enter correct input");
  }

  if (expm.test(e) == false) {
    Err_Arr.push("Enter correct input");
  }

  if (expy.test(f) == false) {
    Err_Arr.push("Enter correct input");
  }

  if (cvv.test(g) == false) {
     Err_Arr.push("Enter correct input");
  }

  if (Err_Arr.length > 0) {
       alert(Err_Arr.join("\n"));
  }

}
```

```html
<h2>Part 3 - Javascript with Alert Box</h2>
<form method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="form1">
  Customer name: <input id="cname" type="text" name="cname" autocomplete="off"> <br \> Order date: <input id="odate" type="text" name="odate" autocomplete="off"> <br \> Contact number: (e.g. 98765432) <input id="cno" type="text" name="cno" autocomplete="off">  <br \> Credit card number: (e.g. 123456789) <input id="ccn" type="text" name="ccn" autocomplete="off"> <br \> Expiry date - month part (mm): <input id="expm" type="text" name="expm" autocomplete="off"> <br \> Expiry date - year part (yyyy): <input id="expy"
    type="text" name="expy" autocomplete="off"> <br \> CVV Number (e.g. 123): <input id="cvv" type="text" name="cvv" autocomplete="off"> <br \>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I expect the whole web form to give me a whole list of alerts in the conditions that I did not satisfy for the if statements. Instead, my code is not running at all.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#pattern

Comment: @connexo I do not want the inputs to use the "pattern" attribute. Strictly javascript.

Comment: Why reinvent what is already there?

Comment: @connexo oh. it's a requirement for my university assignment.

Comment: You have a number of unclosed string literal declarations. `Err_Arr.push("Enter correct input);`.

Comment: onsubmit="return validateForm()" - try remove return

Comment: @connexo yes i realized. but the code still doesnt work.

Comment: @ValK nope. doesn't work still

Comment: @alonelycoder I was able to execute your sample code perfectly. Please check the answer if it works on your side.

Comment: `odate.test(b)` must be `b.test(odate)`. Fix all other tests accordingly.

Comment: `"message": "SyntaxError: unmatched ) in regular expression"`

Comment: Probably from `/0[0-1]1[0-9]){2}/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intent of your code is correct. Reason why alerts doesn't show:

- A syntax error in `var e`. notice the missing pair of the parenthesis. should be `/0[0-1]1([0-9]){2}/;`
- `.test()` is used incorrectly. please refer to [w3schools tutorial how to use test](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_test.asp). Basically, `test()` is a method in the `Regexp` object in javascript. So it should be like `regexObject.test(yourString)`

Fixing all that most likely will make your code run without issues.

```js
function validateForm() {
        var cname = document.getElementById("cname").value;

        var Err_Arr = [];
        var a = new RegExp(/^(\w\w+)\s(\w+)$/);

        if (cname == null || cname == "") {
          Err_Arr.push("Please Enter Info - Customer Name");
        }

        if (!a.test(cname)) {
          Err_Arr.push("Enter correct input");
        }

        if (Err_Arr.length > 0) {
             alert(Err_Arr.join("\n"));
        }
      }
```

```html
<h2>Part 3 - Javascript with Alert Box</h2>
<form method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="form1">
  Customer name:<input id="cname" type="text" name="cname" autocomplete="off"> <br \> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes:

- an invalid regex for `e` as it has unbalanced parentheses
- Strings don't have a `test` method; regexes do
- The suggestion for the credit card number in your HTML would not pass the corresponding regex (that requires 16 digits)

There are also some shorter ways to do things:

```
if (cname == null || cname == "")
```

can be just:

```
if (!cname)
```

More importantly, you have a lot of code repetition. You could avoid that by doing things in a loop:

```js
function validateForm() {
    var validations = [
        { input: "cname", regex: /^(\w\w+)\s(\w+)$/, name: "Customer name" },
        { input: "odate", regex: /^(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/, name: "Order date" },
        { input: "cno", regex: /^\d{8}$/, name: "Contact No" },
        { input: "ccn", regex: /^\d{16}$/, name: "Credit Card Number" },
        { input: "expm", regex: /^0?[1-9]|1[012]$/, name: "Expiry Month" }, // Correct regex
        { input: "expy", regex: /^\d{4}$/, name: "Expiry Year" },
        { input: "cvv", regex: /^\d{3}$/, name: "CVV No" }
    ];

    var errors = validations.map(({input, regex, name}) => {
        var value = document.getElementById(input).value;
        if (!value) return "Please Enter Info - " + name;
        if (!regex.test(value)) return "Enter correct input - " + name;
    }).filter(Boolean);
    if (errors.length) {
       alert(errors.join("\n"));
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<h2>Part 3 - Javascript with Alert Box</h2>
<form method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()" name="form1">
  Customer name: <input id="cname" type="text" name="cname" autocomplete="off"> <br \> 
  Order date: <input id="odate" type="text" name="odate" autocomplete="off"> <br \> 
  Contact number: (e.g. 98765432) <input id="cno" type="text" name="cno" autocomplete="off">  <br \> 
  Credit card number: (e.g. 1234567890123456) <input id="ccn" type="text" name="ccn" autocomplete="off"> <br \> 
  Expiry date - month part (mm): <input id="expm" type="text" name="expm" autocomplete="off"> <br \> 
  Expiry date - year part (yyyy): <input id="expy"  type="text" name="expy" autocomplete="off"> <br \> 
  CVV Number (e.g. 123): <input id="cvv" type="text" name="cvv" autocomplete="off"> <br \>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```